# How is /dev/null created on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, udev

Just wondering how is /dev/null created on my archlinux box.

I investigated [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev) rules under `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d`, but there are no rules relating to to name `null`.

```
> ag null /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/*
```

and `/etc/udev/rules.d` is empty.
So I run:

```
> udevadm test /class/mem/null
...rules ignored.
11859 strings (99853 bytes), 9914 de-duplicated (79634 bytes), 1946 trie nodes used
handling device node '/dev/null', devnum=c1:3, mode=0666, uid=0, gid=0
preserve permissions /dev/null, 020666, uid=0, gid=0
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/1:3' to '../null'
ACTION=add
DEVMODE=0666
DEVNAME=/dev/null
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/mem/null
MAJOR=1
MINOR=3
SUBSYSTEM=mem
USEC_INITIALIZED=3266478398
```

There seems to be a rule matching `null`?

And with `systemd`, there is something called `systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service`. But I still cannot figure out if it created `/dev/null` and how?

```
> systemctl list-units | grep tmpfiles-setup-dev
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                          loaded active exited    Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
```

Comment: According to [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lfs/LFS-BOOK-6.1.1-HTML/chapter06/devices.html), `/dev/null` needs to be prsent when `udev` is launched so it can't be created by `udev` itself.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/null` is created by the kernel at boot time, because the kernel requires it. It's not `udev` specific.

Comment: Is it created by the kernel? I would have assumed it was put there at install-time.